# Can we consolidate multiple questions about changing primary email on Google?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

I've found multiple questions about changing the primary email in ones Google Account to a non-gmail email and what's worse is the correct answer doesn't have the highest vote. Is there anyway we can create redirects for identical questions? Furthermore, I am new and it is not a good sign if a lot of people who believe there is nothing one can do about a subject rules the thread when there is in fact an answer.

Anyway, I'm just starting this question because I can't vote up the answers that basically point others to go to Google Products and have them delete their gmail feature which can only be done if one has an alternate email address.

Answer (score 4):

In general, questions on StackExchange sites can be closed as duplicates of one another.  For example, here is [a discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77103/improve-tools-for-closing-as-duplicate) on the main meta site about improving the mechanism for closing as duplicates.

I'm not very active on Web Apps, so I'm not sure what the preferred approach is here, but my suggestion would be to collect a list of the various questions that you think are duplicates, and which one you think should be the primary question, and edit that into your question.  Then hopefully high-rep users or mods will agree with you, and consolidate the questions.

Sadly there's not much you can do about an incorrect answer being upvoted, other than downvoting bad answers, upvoting good ones, and leaving comments explaining why the wrong answer is wrong.  All of which you will be able to do soon once you acquire some reputation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of questions that migth share the same foundations:

- Create new consumer account without Gmail
- Accidental change of primary account due to adding Gmail
- Remove Gmail but keeping access to / data from other services
- Convert consumer account into a Apps / G Stuite / Workspace account

It might worthy to review the current documenation and external user created resources to decide if we point users to read them before asking a question or how to handle this as Q&A.